# How to calculate the summation of this sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability

$$\sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}e^{iuj}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}$$ Here, $i$ stand for complex number $i$, $j \in N$, and $0<p<1$. Since it is a sequence, I coundn't find any formula for this.

The answer is $(pe^{iu}+1-p)^n$, I know the answer but I dont know how to derive this.

Comment: Just use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the formula of Binomial Theorem? There is:

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^{k} y^{n-k};$$

So, in your problem we have $x = p e^{iu}$ and $y = 1-p$.

Answer (score 0):

Justo note that $e^{iuj}p^j=(pe^{iu})^j$ and use the binomial theorem

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}e^{iuj}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}=\sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}(e^{iu}p)^j(1-p)^{n-j}=(e^{iu}p+(1-p))^n$